# Differential equations basic problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I know this is a basic Physics problems but somehow I can't solve it.
We have the differential equation: $2x''x^2 - 4 x^2x' - 2  x^3 = 0$

We have to conclude that the system:

$x' = y $

$y' = 2y + x$

..is equivalent to the differential equation. How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to integrate whole equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \neq 0$, then solving for $x^{\prime\prime}$ we get
$$
x^{\prime\prime} = 2x^{\prime} + x
$$
Now let $y = x^{\prime}$. Then
$$
y^{\prime} = x^{\prime\prime} = 2x^{\prime} + x = 2y + x
$$

Comment: @alo: Thank you! Let to ask just one thing.. Can I solve the equation for x'' in Maxima or Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to solve it in Maxima, not sure about alpha. Or you should be able to solve it by hand, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Comment: @pluralism: See [*WA Solution*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%27%27+x%5E2+-+4+x%5E2+x%27+-+2++x%5E3+%3D+0)